Identifying a component from an Acer Aspire F15 Laptop
I am currently working on a Laptop for a client, I have identified this part as a potential cause of the failure to boot, yet I have no Idea what it is?, what it does?, how to test it properly, and where to buy a replacement.
I believe it is just a resistor but that is a guess at best, I did try searching for the part on Digikey and Arrow, yet they provided no help.
The characters on top read 1R0539E18
The component in question is circled. I apologise in advance if this post doesn't meet the standards set by the community, I am also happy to clarify any further information that may be required. Thank you in advance.


Looks like a 1uH inductor. Finding the exact model will be hard and requires at least the dimensions.

I hope that the reason you think it is at fault is not because you measured a short with multimeter.

Very unlikely the inductor is at fault. Look elsewhere.

It's a 1uH inductor of some kind. Here is an example made by Cyntec which has similar markings, so it may or may not be the same manufacturer as yours.

(Source: lcsc.com)
The function in the circuit is impossible to tell without knowing the circuit. It may be used as a power filter or in a switching converter.
Since it doesn't show signs of damage, I think it's unlikely that it's broken. You can test if it failed open by measuring the resistance.
